# Which probability to get any combination on flop with AA?

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-theory, probability

I want know which probability to get various combinations with AA vs 1 opponent to flop:

1. Which probability to get one pair?
2. Which probability to get two pair?
3. Which probability to get set?
4. Which probability to get full house (AAA**)?
5. Which probability to get full house (***AA)?
6. Which probability to get four of a kind?
7. Which probability to get flush draw?

Comment: It is easy to find using https://www.flopzilla.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be inaccurate as I'm doing the calculations by hand, but. Software is for people who can't do things themselves :)

- You get one pair or better 100% of the time.
- You get two pair 15.1% of the time. (full-house excluded)
- You get a set 11.6% of the time. (full-house excluded)
- You get quads 0.5% of the time
- You get an AA-XXX full-house 0.27% of the time.
- You get an AAA-XX full-house 0.25% of the time.
- You get a flush draw 2.2% of the time.